# How to compare two non-random access iterator in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator, find

I have this :

```
vector<int> vec = {10, 4, 18, 7, 2, 10, 25, 30};
auto& pos25 = find(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), 25);
auto& pos18 = find(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), 18);
```

Now, i want to make a query to search for *7* between there two positions. I can just use `operator<` between `pos25` and `pos18` since they're random acess iterators and then I can `find` the location of *7* within that range.

But what if my container is a `forward_list`. How will I implement that since I don't have an `operator<` to compare these two iterators; hence I can't know whether `pos25` or `pos18` occur first to give a range to the `find` function.

I found this method in a book :

```
pos18 = find (vec.begin(), vec.end(), // range
18); // value
pos25 = find (vec.begin(), pos18, // range
25); // value
if (pos18 != coll.end() && pos25 != pos18) {
// pos25 is in front of pos18
// so, only [pos25,pos18) is valid
...
}
else {
pos25 = find (pos25, vec.end(), // range
25); // value
if (pos25 != coll.end()) {
// pos18 is in front of pos25
// so, only [pos18,pos25) is valid
...
}
else {
// 18 and/or 25 not found
...
}
}
```

Though this is simple enough, is there anything more efficient?

Comment: This is tediously complicated, but you won't beat it for efficiency - it finds `pos18` by searching through the whole vector, then it finds `pos25` by searching first from `begin` to `pos18`, and then from `pos18` to `end` - so it is optimal.  I don't think you can do better.

Comment: @MartinBonner This looks at elements more than once, so you can *definitely* beat it for efficiency see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41143158/2642059).

Comment: @JonathanMee: Ah ha!  I was think of efficiency in terms of "number of comparisons", not "number of iterations" - which I usually think of as "cheap" - but you are right.  In the case of a linked list, this is a poor intuition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterating over a linked list is of relatively high cost because of the potential accesses to memory that must be made. You'll want to minimize those accesses. There are a couple things you could do to that end:

1. Use [`find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to search for *either 18* or *25*
2. Then search *from* that point with `find_if` again for either *7* or the other bound
3. If the other bound was found 1<sup>st</sup> there is no intervening *7* if the *7* was found first ensure the other bound exists

So your code could look like this:

```
const auto start = find_if(cbegin(vec), cend(vec), [](const auto& i){ return i == 18 || i == 25; });
const auto target = find_if(start, cend(vec), [finish = *start == 18 ? 25 : 18](const auto& i){ return i == 7 || i == finish; });
const auto finish = *target == 7 ? find(target, cend(vec), *start == 18 ? 25 : 18) : cend(vec);
```

After this if `finish` doesn't point to `cend(vec)` then `target` is a valid pointer to the 1<sup>st</sup> *7* in the range.

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/9a8HVW)

---

[Vlad from Moscow's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41143465/2642059) cleverly avoided the need for lambdas by using [`find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of), but it iterated over the contents of `vec` more than once, making it more expensive than my algorithm. The marriage of these 2 algorithms results in an algorithm that is faster than my original while preserving the benefit of only accessing each element once:

```
const int a[] = { 18, 25 };
const auto start = find_first_of(cbegin(vec), cend(vec), cbegin(a), cend(a));
const int b[] = { *start == *cbegin(a) ? *crbegin(a) : *cbegin(a), 7 };
const auto target = find_first_of(start, cend(vec), cbegin(b), cend(b));
const auto finish = *target == *crbegin(b) ? find(target, cend(vec), *cbegin(b)) : cend(vec);
```

Again if `finish` doesn't point to `cend(vec)` then `target` is a valid pointer to the 1<sup>st</sup> 7 in the range.

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/GuH6mN)

Answer (score 3):

For starters this code snippet (if to update a typo) is wrong

```
vector<int> vec = {10, 4, 18, 7, 2, 10, 25, 30};
auto& pos25 = find(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), 25);
auto& pos18 = find(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), 18);
```

You may not bind a temporary object with a non-constant reference.

As for this approach

```
pos18 = find (vec.begin(), vec.end(), // range
18); // value
pos25 = find (vec.begin(), pos18, // range
25); // value
```

then you will need to check many conditions. For example before calling

```
pos25 = find (vec.begin(), pos18, // range
25); // value
```

you should check whether `pos19` is not equal to `vec.end()`.

As for determining which iterator is less or greater than you can use standard function `std::distance`.  However it is inefficient applied to iterators of the container `std::forward_list`.

A more efficient approach is to use standard algorithm `std::find_first_of` instead of the algorithm `std::find` to find the first iterator of the range.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = { 10, 4, 18, 7, 2, 10, 25, 30 };
    int a[] = { 25, 18 };

    auto first = std::find_first_of(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(),
        std::begin(a), std::end(a));

    auto last = vec.cend();
    auto target = vec.cend();

    if (first != vec.cend())
    {
        last = std::find(first, vec.cend(),
            *first == a[0] ? a[1] : a[0]);
    }

    if (last != vec.cend())
    {
        target = std::find(first, last, 7);
    }

    if (target != vec.end())
    {
        std::cout << 7 << " is between " << *first
            << " and " << *last << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
7 is between 18 and 25
```

Comment: The use of `a` to avoid the need for lambdas is clever +1. But this algorithm iterates over elements of `vec` more than once which is unnecessary. An answer that combines your and my ideas would probably be the best :)

Comment: @JonathanMee I have not understood what you mean saying that the algorithm iterates over elements of vec more than once.

Comment: I've updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41143158/2642059) to combine our algorithms, but for completness of explanation note that my solution's `target` begins it's `find_first_of` range at `start` and `finish` begins it's `find_first_of` range at `target`, so there's never an element that's inspected more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any options to compare two `ForwardIterator`'s other than `operator ==`. This means that you have only two ways here:

1. Use `std::find` to ensure the iterators belong to a particular part of your array. This method is implemented in code you cited and in the @Jonathan's answer.
2. Compare two iterators by writing a special procedure for such operations.

For example, you can write the following code:

```
template<typename ForwardIterator>
bool less(ForwardIterator lhs, ForwardIterator rhs, ForwardIterator end) {
    if (lhs == rhs) {
        return false; // Equal
    }
    while (lhs++ != end) {
        if (lhs == rhs) {
            return true; // rhs is after lhs
        }
    }
    return false; // lhs is after rhs
}
```

Please also note that this procedure assumes that both iterators belong to the same container and has linear time complexity.

Personally, I would recommend in such situation using a `RandomAccessIterator`. Yes, `std::list` does not provide one, but you may use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: A `list` does not provide a "RandomAccessIterator"... and "eating a cactus" seriously? I think your answer would be improved by removing such flavor text.

Comment: @JonathanMee Fixed